# How to calculate moving average from bottom to up

Tags: r, moving-average

There is dataframe `df` , how to add `moving_average` variable as image ? I want to the calculate bottom up and just calculate two dataes.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(value=c(1:10))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ave` like below

```
transform(
    df,
    moving_average = ave(value,
        rev((seq_along(value)-1) %/% 2),
        FUN = \(x) c(NA, mean(x))[seq_along(x)]
    )
)
```

which gives

```
   value moving_average
1      1             NA
2      2            1.5
3      3             NA
4      4            3.5
5      5             NA
6      6            5.5
7      7             NA
8      8            7.5
9      9             NA
10    10            9.5
```

Comment: Thanks,it's greate . If remove  [seq_along(x)] , the result will be the same , what's the purpose ? @ThomasIsCoding

Comment: @anderwyang in case the moving window is of length 1

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with package `zoo`.

```r
df <- data.frame(value=0:10) 

df$moving_average <- zoo::rollmeanr(df$value, k = 2L, fill = NA)
is.na(df$moving_average) <- (seq_along(df$value) - 1L) %% 2L == 1L
df
#>    value moving_average
#> 1      0             NA
#> 2      1             NA
#> 3      2            1.5
#> 4      3             NA
#> 5      4            3.5
#> 6      5             NA
#> 7      6            5.5
#> 8      7             NA
#> 9      8            7.5
#> 10     9             NA
#> 11    10            9.5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Reverse it, use `rollapply` with `by = 2` and `align = "left"` and reverse it back or with `ave` reverse `gl`.

```
library(zoo)
df <- data.frame(value=0:10) 

transform(df, ma = rev(rollapply(rev(value), 2, mean, by = 2, fill = NA,
  align = "left")))

# or
n <- nrow(df)
transform(df, ma = ave(value, rev(gl(n, 2, n)),
  FUN = \(x) rollmeanr(x, 2, fill = NA)))
```

Either one gives

```
   value  ma
1      0  NA
2      1  NA
3      2 1.5
4      3  NA
5      4 3.5
6      5  NA
7      6 5.5
8      7  NA
9      8 7.5
10     9  NA
11    10 9.5
```